# minify multiple css files for angular 6 project using webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, angular6, minify, webpack-3

Angular 6 compresses the CSS file but didn't minify it. I need to minify CSS files.

Currently I'm using these commands for production build.

package.json

```
"build": "run-s build:client build:aot build:server",
"build:client": "ng build --prod --build-optimizer && ng run elgrocer:server",
"build:aot": "ng build --aot --prod --build-optimizer --output-hashing=all",
"build:server": "webpack -p"
```

webpack.config.js

```
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].js'
      },
      module: {
        rules: [
          { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
        ]
      },
      optimization: {
        minimizer: [
          new UglifyJsPlugin()
        ]
      },
      plugins: [
        new CompressionPlugin({
          algorithm: 'gzip'
        })
      ]
```

currently its adding the css style in index.html file like that.

```
<style ng-transition="app">.sign-in[_ngcontent-sc6] {
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.sign-up[_ngcontent-sc6] {
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 6px 14px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    border: 2px solid var(--Primary-Brand-1)!important;
    color: var(--Primary-Brand-1);
}

.sign-in[_ngcontent-sc6] {
    background: var(--Primary-Brand-1);
}

.top-nav[_ngcontent-sc6]   li[_ngcontent-sc6] {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px
}</style>
```

desired results

```
<style ng-transition="app">.sign-in[_ngcontent-sc6]{font-size:15px;padding:8px 16px;border-radius:100px;}.sign-up[_ngcontent-sc6]{font-size:15px;padding:6px 14px;border-radius:100px;border:2px solid var(--Primary-Brand-1)!important;color:var(--Primary-Brand-1);}.sign-in[_ngcontent-sc6]{background:var(--Primary-Brand-1);}.top-nav[_ngcontent-sc6]li[_ngcontent-sc6]{list-style:none;display:inline-block;margin-left:10px}</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CssMinimizerWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/css-minimizer-webpack-plugin/). Install it first:

```
$ npm install css-minimizer-webpack-plugin --save-dev
```

Then add it to your config:

```js
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require('css-minimizer-webpack-plugin');

...

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
    ]
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin(),
      new CssMinimizerPlugin()
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CompressionPlugin({
      algorithm: 'gzip'
    })
  ]
```

### Edit from your edit

Maybe you have this behavior because you're not extracting the css in a separate file, so you can use use [HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/) to do the job:

```
npm install --save-dev html-webpack-plugin
```

In you config add the plugin:

```js
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');


  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),
    new CompressionPlugin({
      algorithm: 'gzip'
    })
  ]
```

Comment: it didn't work for me. I have update the question with some more detail.

Comment: I have separate CSS file for every component. it converted into style tag and merged into html file by angular when creating production build. I have tried the both plug in  but they didn't work for me.